# How does JavaScript compare a number to a string?

Tags: javascript, comparison, comparison-operators

I know the meaning of `===`: it will check whether the operands are identical or not，so

- `1 === '1'` will give `false` and
- `1 == '1'` will give `true`,

But `typeof 1` is `number` and `typeof '1'` is `string`, so how is JavaScript comparing `1 == '1'`? Are there any conversions happening? If so, which ones?

Comment: the standard: http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3

Answer (score 4):

If types are number and string,

JavaScript will convert the string to a number.

Out of [Annotated ECMAScript 5.1](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3):

> The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or
>   false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> ...
>
> 5. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the
>   comparison x == ToNumber(y). 
>   6. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is
>   Number, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.

Comment: It's not converted with parseInt, ToNumber behaves differently.

Comment: @bfavaretto There is no ToNumber in JavaScript

Comment: It's an internal operation defined in the specification, it's not exposed to the language. See http://es5.github.io/#x9.3

Comment: Actually, what I just said isn't correct: it's exposed indirectly via the `Number` constructor http://es5.github.io/#x15.7.1

Answer (score 0):

You can do `1 == parseInt("1")` to parse the string into an integer.

Comment: yes, but if you do not parseint the string, if you just use 1 == '1', it will say true

Comment: Are you asking if it will say true if you don't do a parseInt?

Comment: Yes, it will be true.  It's like PHP where if you did 1 === '1' then it would return false.

Comment: Using a radix of 1? How on earth would that work? The radix needs to be between  2 and 36.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I'm not familiar with the radix of 1.  I did a console.log in firebug with 1 === '1' and it returns false.

Comment: The second parameter to `parseInt` is the radix. `parseInt("1", 1)` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Use String()

It converts the input to a string before doing a comparison.

Example:

```
var test1= 1;
var test2= "1";

var answer = String(test1) === String(test2);
```

Answer will equal true in this case.

Comment: yes, but if you only type 1 == '1', it will be true, so how javascript compare it? does javascript will convert the test1 to string automatically?

Comment: This answers your question a bit better then, I thought you were wanting to know how to convert the values before comparing! http://stackoverflow.com/a/7625195/2509123