# Javascript comparisons

Tags: javascript

I would like to know why the following comparisons in javascript will give me different results.

```
(1==true==1)
true

(2==true==2)
false

(0==false==0)
false

(0==false)
true
```

I can not figure out why.

Comment: I'm wondering how you ended up with those lines of code

Comment: Related: [Does it matter which equals operator (== vs ===) I use in JavaScript comparisons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) and [Implicit data type conversion in JavaScript when comparing integer with string using ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625144/implicit-data-type-conversion-in-javascript-when-comparing-integer-with-string-u)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks, I will read.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615214/in-javascript-why-is-0-equal-to-false-but-not-false-by-itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tests are equivalent to these:

```
(true==1)
true

(false==2)
false

(true==0)
false
```

which is equivalent to these:

```
(1==1)
true

(0==2)
false

(1==0)
false
```

In each case the `==` converts the boolean to a number `1` or `0`. So the first `==` in each one gives the initial `true/false` value, which is then used as the first operand for the second `==`.

---

Or to put it all inline:

```
((1==true)==1)
((1==1)   ==1)
((true)   ==1)
((1)      ==1)
true

((2==true)==2)
((2==1)   ==2)
((false)  ==2)
((0)      ==2)
false

((0==false)==0)
((0==0)    ==0)
((false)   ==0)
((0)       ==0)
false
```

Comment: Why (2==true) is false?

Comment: I am almost understanding. Why (2) is true and (2==true) is false?

Comment: Because it is true that 2 exists as a value, but is false that 2 == true =]

Comment: @user2045806: Because (2) is a simple "truthy" evaluation, so any non-zero (or non-NaN) number is considered `true`, but the `==` is doing type coercion, where `true` becomes the number `1` and the number `2` is not equal to the number `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because it is parsed as such:

```
( (0 == false) == 0 )
```

Which would be saying

```
( true == false )
```

Answer (score 0):

Each of this operation is done in two steps.

```
(1==true==1)
```

first operation is 1 == true => true

So second is true == 1 => true

```
(2==true==2)
```

first operation is 2 == true => false (just number 1 is equivalent to true in js)

So second is false == 2 => true

```
(0==false==0)
```

first operation is 0 == false => true

So second is true == 0 => false